# How do i push elements to javascript object in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to learn knockout.I am trying to learn foreach binding in knockout .

First I declared a javascript object

```
 var people = function()
 {
   var self = this;   
   this.firstname = ko.observable("")
   this.lastname = ko.observable("")
 }
```

I tried to push elements into the javacript object

var x = new people();

```
x.push({firstName: "bob" ,lastName:'gill'});
```

I added viewmodel

```
function TestViewModel()
{
var self = this;    
this.person = ko.observableArray({people});    

}
```

created an instance of viewmodel and pushed the elements

```
 var viewmodel = new TestViewModel(); 

viewmodel.person.push(x);
```

Finally binded the elements

```
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE I trying to achieve

http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5592/

I want the following output

```
firstname   lastname
bob          marley
tom           brady
George      clooney
```

Comment: `.push()` applies to *arrays*, but `x` is *not* an array, it is an instance of `people`.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do. Have you tried anything else? Have you looked at the console in your browser? The error you are getting now is that push isn't a function. You have no method push declared on your 'people' object. I can't tell you what you need to change exactly until you can state clearly what you are trying to do. At the moment, you question has nothing to do with knockout, but basic javascript.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment: I am trying to add array of people objects into person and then use foreach binding to display all the elements in the array

Comment: I am trying to implement this

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: @peinearydevelopment: please see the updated question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5594/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues to address in your JSFiddle:

1. Your `thead` HTML is missing a closing `>`
2. As user nnnnnn mentioned, you are trying to push to an instance of People, not the array that is bound to your foreach
3. Your value bindings do not match your people property names (`firstname` vs `firstName`)

Here's an updated JSFiddle that implements a basic foreach example: http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5593/

Answer (score 0):

To answer it, follow an example, which I have an amount of information into a base of data and I will push it into a data table in my front-end.

```
function tableData(){
 <cfoutput>
    var newDados = #serializeJSON(mySQLData)#;
    var dataABC = newDados.ABC;
    var dataXYZ = newDados.XYZ;
  </cfoutput>
  //cfoutput is a Cold Fusion parameter to receive data from SQL.
```

In this case I serialize newDados to an object. 
ABC and XYZ are objects sons of newDados.

In this case, I want to mix and push both objects child in a single object to work these parameters together. So I use a `forEach` function:

```
  allData = new Array();

  dadosABC.forEach(function(obj){
    allData.push(obj);
  });
  XYZ.forEach(function(obj){
    allData.push(obj);
  });
  //Here allData have already receiving data of both newDados object child

  allDataSize = allData.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < sizePreenc; i++) {
    allData[i] = new Array();
    tableData[i].push(allData[i]);
    tableData[i].push(allData[i].firstName);
    tableData[i].push(allData[i].lastName);
    tableData[i].push(allData[i].age);
    tableData[i].push(allData[i].gender);
  };
  drawGrid('');
 };
```

This way, I push my datas to table, or whatever I want to.